# React -- how to break out of ' React.Children.forEach ' loop?

Tags: reactjs

If I'm looping through a react component's children like so:

```
React.Children.forEach(this.props.children, (child) => {

       //checking child's props and such...
      if (child.props[someprop] == some condition) {
         break out of loop here
      }
});
```

But how does one break out of this loop?  I want to check certain props on the children and break out on a condition. Is there a break or exit for or something for this? Or is there another way to loop through React's children?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cant break out of the [`forEach`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrenforeach) but you could use the [`toArray`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrentoarray) method like so:

```js
const children = React.Children.toArray(this.props.children);
for ( let child of children ) {
    if (child.props[someprop] == some condition) {
        break;
    }
}
```